# Capistrano Deploy (cap deploy) failing, Authentication errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, github, capistrano

I can't seem to get capistrano deploy working.

Here's a bit of background:

The server is currently running, and has a deploy on it that worked successfully yesterday (this was the first deploy I've done).

Today, I wake up, write up a fix for a few bugs, and try to deploy, but I get the following authentication related errors on my Ubuntu box when trying to deploy to my Ubuntu server:

http://privatepaste.com/f774f4b424

I'm using github.

The weird thing is though, I can successfully clone my repo and SSH to git@github.com, and it will work and authentication will be accepted. So why is capistrano having such a hard time? I don't really know what to do at this point. Here is my deploy file (which hasn't changed, so should still be working):

http://privatepaste.com/bed7556002/afafaf

I'd really love some help here. Thanks!

Comment: Did you enter your server's ssh key on github?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things to try:

1. if it's just a fairly small app in which you will be doing all the deploys, I would suggest to use the 'forward_agent' option to access the github repo, this will access github using the ssh key on your local machine, removing the need to setup server keys.

   **ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true**
2. Add the git branch to use

   **set :branch, 'master'**
3. Try removing the **:deploy_via, :remote_cache** option, I have had problems with using that with github sometimes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I figured it out. For some reason, it didn't like the way I was tunneling to my development box from work. 

I was SSH'd into my dev box via PuTTy, and for some reason whilst I'm SSH'd into it from work, cap deploy fails with those errors. I don't understand how or why, but hopefully anyone else having this problem can take this into account as well.